# Lookback API _ProjectHierarchy not scoping down

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

Hi I am fetching the current userstories for a particular iteration using the following code

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch:function(){
        me = this;
        combo = window.parent.Ext4.ComponentQuery.query('rallyiterationcombobox')[0];
        var iterationObjectID = combo.getRecord().data.ObjectID;
        var query1= { _ProjectHierarchy: me.getContext().getProject().ObjectID, Iteration : iterationObjectID , _TypeHierarchy:"HierarchicalRequirement"};
        var fields = ["ObjectID","FormattedID","Name","Parent","Release","Tags","PlanEstimate","ScheduleState","_ValidFrom","_ValidTo"];
        var hydrate = ["Tags","ScheduleState"];
        var post = { find :query1, fields : fields, hydrate : hydrate, pagesize : 10000 };
        var wsid = this.context.getWorkspace().ObjectID;
        var url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/"+ wsid +"/artifact/snapshot/query.js";
        console.log("snapshot url:",url);


            Ext.Ajax.request({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                jsonData : post,
                success: function(res) {
                    res = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                    console.log("The final results are",res);


                },

                failure: function(failure) {
                    console.log("snapshot query failed!",failure);
                }
            });
```

The problem is that I could not get the user stories of the child projects when I specify the parent project in the query. For example if I have the hierarchy like this

```
Project 7890
     User Story 55
     User Story 56
        Project 6543
         User Story 57
           Project 3456
              User Story 777
```

Ideally If I query _ProjectHierarchy: 7890 I should be getting User Story 55,User Story 56,User Story 57,User Story 777 since the query retrieves the multiple work items of itself and its child projects,but here I am only able to get User Story 55,User Story 66(which are userstories of project 7890) but not User Story 57,User Story 777 since those are the User Stories of the child projects. I want to retrieve all User Stories of selected project  and its child projects also(i.e scope down).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [LBAPI Docs](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc) for some good info on this, particularly the difference between _ProjectHierarchy and _ItemHierarchy/_TypeHierarchy.

In your situation, you should probably be using the _ItemHierarchy/_TypeHierarchy:

**Work item hierarchy**

The work item hierarchy traverses a Parent/Child relationship using the _ItemHierarchy field. So if you have this hierarchy:

```
  Story 333
     Story 444
        Story 555
           Story 666
              Defect 777
                 Task 12
              Task 13
        Story 888
        Story 999
```

The document for Story 666 would look like this:

```
  {
     ObjectID: 666,
     Parent: 555,
     _ItemHierarchy: [333, 444, 555, 666],
     ...
  }
```

To retrieve all Stories that descend from Story 333 (includes 333, 444, 555, 666, 888, and 999 but not Defect 777), you would include this clause in your query:

```
  {
     _ItemHierarchy: 333,
     _TypeHierarchy: “HierarchicalRequirement”
  }
```

**Project hierarchy**

The Project hierarchy is also represented as an array starting at a root Project for this Workspace. So if work item 777 is at the bottom of this Project hierarchy:

```
 Project 7890
    Project 6543
       Project 3456
          Work item 777
```

The document for work item 777 would look like this:

```
 {
     ObjectID: 777,
     Project: 3456,
     _ProjectHierarchy: [7890, 6543, 3456],
     ...
 }
```

To retrieve multiple work items that are in Project 7890 or any of its child projects, you would simply include this clause in your query:

```
_ProjectHierarchy: 7890
```

Comment: The problem is that I could not get the user stories of the child projects when I specify the parent project in the query for example

Comment: Are you looking for User Stories in child projects? Your question says "I should get all child user stories" which implies that you are looking for parent/child relationships in an ItemHierarchy. It would help if you could post what you are seeing for results vs. what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Please Look into the question once again.I have edited it so that you can understand more clearly

Comment: Yes I am looking for userstories in the child projects. so when I specify the project hierarchy I need to get the user stories of the Project(value of the projecthierearchy) and also of its child projects