# Lookback API _ProjectHierarchy not returning defects for child project

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I need to get all the defects for a particular project and all of its children.

The [Rally LBAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual/a8ead32afef5fcd29f5532f6b333d4de) documentation says:

```
For a project hierarchy like

    Project 7890
       Project 6543
          Project 3456

to retrieve all work items that are in Project 7890 or any of its child projects,
you would simply include this clause in your query:

   "_ProjectHierarchy": 7890
```

But doing this as in below query

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/XXX/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_ProjectHierarchy":12345,"_TypeHierarchy": "Defect","__At": "current","Release":9999}&fields=["FormattedID","Name","State","OpenedDate","ClosedDate"]&hydrate=["State"]&sort={"FormattedID":1}&start=0&removeUnauthorizedSnapshots=true
```

only return defects for project 12345 but none of its child projects.

I have also read [Lookback API _ProjectHierarchy not scoping down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556923/lookback-api-projecthierarchy-not-scoping-down/15557600#15557600), but it says the same thing written in the doc.

Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Release OID differs for every project so specifying a single Release (9999) is limiting the results to a single project.  To accomplish the same thing you'll get to get all the oids for all the matching releases that for the project scope you want.

Comment: I had no idea that release ID for different projects is different. Thank you so much! :)